# How to remove .vscode folder form my local repository and GitHub repository

Tags: git, gitignore

I have created a project on vs code and initialized it with git. After pushing it to GitHub I realised that it is tracking .vscode folder. Now I added .vscode to my gitignore file but .vscode is still there. I am not able to remove it form my local as well as GitHub repository.